# How to stop all jQ functions related with removed div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have a slider on my page.

[image]

What I want to do is, to remove this slider on video thumb click event and stop **all** functions related with this slider.

Please take a look at [this page](http://pikproduction.az/?lang=az&page=11) with Firefox.
Click on video thumbnail, you'll see what I'm talking about.
The problem is, I'm removing the div (in which jQ functions working inside) on video thumbnail click event. But all slider functions are working after removing slider container div.

## Question

How can I stop all functions related with removed slider container div and all it's child divs?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put this at the top of the involved functions a(),aa(),b() and c()

```
if(!$('.slider_box').length)return;
```